# Is there an ultrasonic mist maker that can create water droplet with diameter 50 microns for aeroponic purposes?

Tags: nutrients

An ultrasonic mist maker seems a superior solution for an aeroponic crop, since there would less problem with clogging, power consumption, noise, etc.

However, current ultrasonic mist maker make really small droplets of size less than 10 microns. It seems 50 microns is the sweet spot needed for long term growth of plants. I have two questions:
1) Is it theoretically possible to create droplet of size 50 microns using ultrasonic technology?
2) If the answer to the above is yes, do you know of a commercial product or even something that can be bought out there and assembeled which can create 50 micron droplets

Comment: 50 microns is 10x larger than the other systems I saw online.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not fit with gardening & landscaping as described in the [Help Center](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).